# Order embeddings: looking for examples and literature

Tags: order-theory

I am looking for explicit examples of order embedding map $f$ for orders of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$:
$$
x\preceq y\;\;iff\;\;f(x)\leq f(y)
$$
E.g. can someone give me an example of such map for the majorization order?
Other examples for other orders?

Thanks

Fabio

Comment: What is the majorization order?

Comment: I meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization